Prove that the minimal polynomial of $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ equals the minimal polynomial of $T$.
This is exercise 5.B.27 in Linear Algebra Done Right, fourth edition by Sheldon Axler:

Suppose $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$, $V$ is finite-dimensional, and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that the minimal polynomial of $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ equals the minimal polynomial of $T$.

There are already answers to this question here and here, but in my attempt below, I am unsure if my justification that $\deg p > \deg q$ implies the above. I explain this more under my attempt below.
My attempt.
Let $q$ be the minimal polynomial of $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ and let $p$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$. Observe that for any $v, u \in V$ we have
$$
p(T_{\mathbb{C}})(u + iv) = p(T)u + ip(T)v = 0
$$
where the last equality follows since $p(T) = 0$. This implies that $p$ is a polynomial multiple of $q$ -- with $p$ monic, there exists a nonzero monic polynomial $s$ such that
$$
p = qs \tag{1}
$$
We want to show $s = 1$. Suppose, for sake of contradiction, $s \neq 1$. Then we have $\deg s \geq 1$. This, along with $(1)$, implies
$$
\deg p > \deg q
$$
This implies that $p$ may have roots that are not roots of $q$. But we know the following facts:

$T$ and $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ share the same eigenvalues.
The roots of the minimal polynomial of an operator are the eigenvalues of the operator.

Thus, the fact $p$ may have roots that are not roots of $q$ contradicts the above two points since they must have exactly the same roots. Hence, the assumption that $s \neq 1$ is incorrect. Thus, we must have $s = 1$, implying $p = q$.
Question.
Clearly, "$p$ may have roots that are not roots of $q$" is not the same as "$p$ has roots that are not roots of $q$". So I'm wondering, because I wrote the former in my proof, does that disqualify my justification that comes after it?

Be careful about your multiplicities here. Do you have that $T$ and $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ have the same eigenvalues with multiplicity?

@Malady Hmm, I don't think so. Looking back at my textbook though, I think my claim that they share the same eigenvalues is incorrect. It's only true when the eigenvalues are in $\mathbb{R}$.

Your sentence "the fact $p$ may have roots that are not roots of $q$ contradicts the above two points" is false. It's a little strange because the word "may" is disguising some existential quantification there, but that's okay. Your real problem is that at this point in Axler you have not proved that $T$ and $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ have the same eigenvalues, because this is not the case.
Here is what I would do. This uses a trick that you have seen before. You have already correctly concluded that $q$ divides $p$. If you could additionally conclude that $p$ divides $q$, you would be done. Let us show that.
$\forall v \in V$:
$$q(T)(v)=q(T)(v+0i)=0$$
and thus $q$ annihilates $T$, and furthermore, $p$ divides $q$.
If two monic polynomials divide each other, they are the same.

Okay, that makes sense! Thank you for your help on this.

Of course. This is often the trick when proving polynomial equality (like when proving set equality you show double-inclusion)
